# php processing a que

Tags: php, mysql

i have a situation in my current development where i need to execute a script over and over again until it processes through a database of email addresses say for example a newsletter to over 2000 contacts

i have a script like this currently

```
define('TO_EMAIL',      "bill@microsoft.com");
define('TO_NAME',       "Bill Gates");
define('FROM_EMAIL',    marketing@apple.com);
define('FROM_NAME', Apple Marketing);                                   
$subject = Our New Phone ;                                   
$message = "just plain text emails";                                 
$result = mail(TO_NAME . ' <' . TO_EMAIL . '>', $subject, $message, 'From: ' .
FROM_NAME . ' <' . FROM_EMAIL . '>',$headers);
```

and i would run this in a mysql while loop

however this can take upto 15-20 minutes to process and will sometimes timeout i know i can change settings in php.ini for the timeout but i wish not to

i wish to have the home page show all the emails addresses to be sent and execute the script for each name on the list so like below

john doe - sent
bob marley - processing
bill gates - to be processed

i wish for it to do the above without leaving the main page so it will execute the script for each and send back the results

how can i achieve this, many thanks in advance

Comment: One possible method for this would be to have a Javascript timeout/loop that posts an ajax request for each item. Then you would simple loop over your list and send each one as a request. This would allow you to also update the response live on the page with a result if it was successful. Once the whole list is complete, you then would fire an event to reload or notify you that it is finished

Comment: any chance you could show some code how this would be possible or link me to a tutorial

Comment: give me 10 ish minutes

Comment: use an ajax loop to request a sending page that will send about 100 emails, then only let a new request go when the request is completed succesfully. That way you can implement a timer too

Comment: @MichaelDibbets any idea how this is done got any code for me to look at

Comment: @Mayhem any luck mate

Comment: Hey sorry, got held up with work. I can still post an example if you need, though you should be able to adapt the idea from "Michael Dibbets" post.

Comment: if you have an example i would love to see it

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting up the sending and the receiving part in ajax.
have some psuedocode

in the sending php

```
// select * from somedatabasetable limit $_POST['start'],$_POST['end']
// ^-- please properly sanitise the post values before inserting into the database
while(having resulsts from database) {
    define('TO_EMAIL',      "bill@microsoft.com");
    define('TO_NAME',       "Bill Gates");
    define('FROM_EMAIL',    marketing@apple.com);
    define('FROM_NAME', Apple Marketing);                                   
    $subject = Our New Phone ;                                   
    $message = "just plain text emails";                                 
    $result = mail(TO_NAME . ' <' . TO_EMAIL . '>', $subject, $message, 'From: ' .
    FROM_NAME . ' <' . FROM_EMAIL . '>',$headers);  
}
```

in your user interface.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // have php load in the total number of emails we have
            numberofentries = <?php
            $var = sql_select_function('select count(*) as numberofemails');
                echo $var; ?>;
            // main function to run for sending the emails
            function runit($start,$max) {
                $end = $start+100;
                // tell it to send stuff by ajax poll
                // when its done restart with new start/max
                // values
                if($end <= $max + 100) {
                jQuery.post('sending.php',{start:$start,end:100}).done(function(){
                            runit($start+100,$max);
                            });
                 }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="runit(0,window.numberofentries)" value="sendemails">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this doesnt display a button for me ?

Comment: ... its psuedo code. something for you to look at and to derive your own ideas from. There can be errors in it and such because i just wrote it out of the top of my head to give you a general gist of the idea.

Comment: had a look at this, really still not what i want i just need to process it for each one in the database 1 by 1

Comment: then change the 100 to a 1... still same concept. You will increase overhead on your database majorly though. sending 100 emails at a time should be done easely. but if you want steps of 1 you will increase execution time majorly, but if you have the patience and want a status callback for each email sent, you can do that.

Comment: yea ill google around i think i dont know much about that type of stuff i would have to see a working demo so i could see what each code does